# C# Service Timeout (30000 milliseconds) waiting for a transaction response in event viewer

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, service, event-log

I have a C# service. It is a memory and CPU pig. It will run all night, moving data in the database. Around 7 am it post to the event viewer, repeatedly,

> Timeout (30000 milliseconds) waiting
>   for a transaction response from the
>   ServName service.

Then it stops unexpectedly. Does anyone have input as to what this message means, or how to diagnose it?

**Update 1**

The DB transactions are not timing out. The service management console is logging this message about trying to control the service.

**Update 2**

The issue here has nothing to do with the database access. It is the service managment console throwing the error as it is trying to control the service.

Comment: [This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814626) might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if the main thread of your service fails to return the control in 30 seconds. However if you check your task manager your service exe will still be running in the background.

Solution is to ensure that the main function of your service returns back within the timeout period.

-Surya

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the transaction last longer than 30 seconds.

Try to send a transaction, something like:

using (transactionscope...)
insert something
sleep 30 seconds
insert something more.

It should give you the same result. If so, try to optimize or configure the transaction timeout.

Hope this helps

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem like a weird, off-base suggestion, but ... has the db run out of transaction log space?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. You are right this has nothing to do with the database. I assume you are running Windows Server 2008 or Vista and that your app is somehow multi threaded.

Try this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972596/